# Generic method with abstract class as parameter

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to create a generic method that takes in a parameter which type is an abstract parameterised class. Inside the method I want to create a instances of the passed parameter given it is a subclass of the abstract type since we cannot instantiate abstract classes.

However I am having some issues.  And the error message says the RuleType cannot be resolved to a type which is not surprising anyway but I don’t know how can I accomplish this.
My current code is below.

```
private <F extends AbstractRule<T>, T> void applyRyle(F cRule,ArrayList<T> aFeatures)
{

    Class RuleType = cRule.getClass();


    // if the parameter passed is a subclass of AbstractRule create some objects
    if(!RuleType.getSuperclass().getName().equals("AbstractRule"))
    {
        ArrayList<RuleType<T>> aRules = new ArrayList<RuleType<T>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            RuleType<T> aRule= new RuleType<T(pattern.getMatrices().size(), 2,aFeatures);
            aRule.initialise(aRule.getMaxLocalLevel());
            aRules.add(aRule);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You _cannot do this._  Or probably anything like it.  `Class` objects are just like other objects -- you cannot use them in the declaration of other variables.

Comment: Can you pass in the class object into the method as well?  applyRule(a, b, MyRule.class);  Would that make it work for you?

Comment: Sure I can pass that but not sure if it's going to work. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of this can be done by using reflection:

```
private <F extends AbstractRule<T>, T> void applyRyle(F cRule, ArrayList<T> aFeatures)
{
     Class<? extends F> ruleType = cRule.getClass();
     // if the parameter passed is a subclass of AbstractRule create some objects
     if(! ruleType.getSuperclass().getName().equals("AbstractRule"))
     {
         ArrayList<? extends F> aRules = new ArrayList<? extends F>();
         for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         {
             F aRule =
                 ruleType
                     .getConstructor(int.class, int.class, ArrayList.class)
                     .newInstance(pattern.getMatrices().size(), 2, aFeatures);
             aRule.initialise(aRule.getMaxLocalLevel());
             aRules.add(aRule);
         }
     }
```

though it's probably not the best way to accomplish what you really want.

Comment: Hey ruakh thanks for the code snipped, at least it compiles, I have modified it little bit but I will probably use the fatory pattern anyway as it seems better practice and more stable as suggested by @Dunes

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't need the following line, because your generic declaration guarentees that  cRule will be an instance of `AbstractRule`.

```
if (!RuleType.getSuperclass().getName().equals("AbstractRule"))
```

The normal and better way of checking for the above at runtime would be to use `instanceof`

```
if (!cRule instanceof AbstractRule)
```

As for your `ArrayList` declarations you could just do the following:

```
ArrayList<F<T>> aRules = new ArrayList<F<T>>();
```

Note, however, that `F` is not the same as the actual solid class of `aRule`. `F` will be the type that the method was called with. That is, `F` will be wider than the class of `aRule` (it may include other subclasses of `F` that are not subclasses of the class of `aRule`).

However, you cannot directly create new instances of `F`. You instead need to have some delegate method that will do it for you. That is, you cannot write `new F()`. What we could do though (since we already have a concrete instance of `F`) is add an abstract method to `AbstractRule` that can create new instances of itself eg.

```
public interface AbstractRule<T extends AbstractRule> {
    T newRule(some parameters you need in the constructor);
}
```

Now we can write:

```
F newRule = aRule.newRule(pattern.getMatrices().size(), 2,aFeatures);
```

Comment: So basically a Factory pattern right ? and also you said that I don't need `if (!RuleType.getSuperclass().getName().equals("AbstractRule")) ` but I am trying to test whether the parameter type is a subclass and not ( subclass or actuall class ) which instanceof is doing

Comment: Yes, a factory pattern, that's right. With regards to your test, the problem is it only tests for a direct subclass (ie. it will miss subclasses of subclasses of AbstractRule). In addition the word abstract implies that a class should not be directly instantiated -- that is, you should never have an object whose class is `AbstractRule`.

Comment: Hmmm good point, seems like the fatory pattern is the way to go then ?. And thanks for pointing the obvious that whatever was passed to the method it has to be a subclass anyway so if parameter is a `instanceof` it has to be subclass anyway, good point. Regarding factory pattern I did not think of subclasses of subclasses and so on. But it could be in the future. Thanks